# ssh -p 29418 user@samehostip fails

Tags: ssh, jenkins, gerrit

I am setting up jenkins and gerrit on the same host, and one thing I need is to have gerrit and jenkins communicate with each other.

When I add the ip address of the host (say 10.25.26.27) then I am not able to get the gerrit trigger to connect to 10.25.26.27. To debug, I tried:

`ssh -p 29418 user@10.25.26.27 -v`

Due diligence with ssh-keygen and copying the id_rsa.pub has been done.

The output of the above command is:

```
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.25.26.27 [10.25.26.27] port 29418.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type 3
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.10
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version GerritCodeReview_3.2.2 (APACHE-SSHD-2.4.0)
debug1: no match: GerritCodeReview_3.2.2 (APACHE-SSHD-2.4.0)
debug1: Authenticating to 10.25.26.27:29418 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: ecdh-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com compression: none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:y/+sp8pk2QcG5EXarPQs3zZrmvbf23ZKp8BF6gtZHEY
debug1: Host '[10.25.26.27]:29418' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Skipping ssh-dss key /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa - not in PubkeyAcceptedKeyTypes
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering ECDSA public key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

However, when I try the same from another ip address, say 10.24.25.29, I can connect successfully.

I need to run both gerrit and jenkins from the same host. Appreciate help on debugging this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server didn't accept any of your keys. Check that you have authorized one or more of your ssh keys on the server.

Further, you cannot use the DSA key `id_dsa` because the server does not accept this key type. It must be one of the other key types.

Comment: Thank you. This helped, Im able to do it after adding the key to the gerrit server.